# How can I list each row that matches a string, set by a dropdown? Filter? VLookup? Query?

Tags: google-sheets

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mvBFBuRUl2qiPktE1Y4lCTeaSK4BwJ7S4Nf0S33LTRg/edit?usp=sharing

On Sheet2 I am wanting to show all the columns associated with a specific string that comes from a dropdown data validation. I have tried using VLOOKUP but that only outputs the first entry found, I want to print every entry along the row.

I put an example of what I am trying to get it to look like but not sure if VLOOKUP or QUERY or FILTER or something else is what I need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example spreadsheet, sheet 2, delete everything in the range F3:I and then enter in F3

```
=query(A:D, "where D='"&F2&"'",1)
```

If you want to reference the data on the sheet you'll have to use

```
=query('Draft Board'!A:D, "where D='"&F2&"'",1)
```

See if that works ?